# Javascript substr problems

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a cross browser animationListener, and have an issue with the `substr` function!

```
function animationEventListener(elem, listener, callback){
       if(!elem){return;}

    if(listener.length < 0){ console.error("Add event type listener"); }

    listener = listener.toLowerCase();

    var _prefix = ["", "o", "webkit", "MS"];
    var _anmkeyword = new String("animation");
    var _keywordlength = _anmkeyword.length;
    var _nlistener;

    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(_prefix[i] == "MS" || _prefix[i] == "webkit"){
            var _ol = _keywordlength + 1;
            _nlistener = listener.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() 
                + listener.substr(1, listener.length - (listener.length - _keywordlength)-1) 
                + listener.substr(9, 10).toUpperCase() 
                + listener.substr(_keywordlength+1, listener.length);
        }    
        console.log(_prefix[i] + listener + "\n" + _nlistener);
    }

}
```

try it you see:

```
 listener = "animationend";
 listener.substr(9, 10);    // returns "end";
```

WHY?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: You might have wanted to use the `substring` method. Check out the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) for it, might help.

Comment: in this code substr need result one letter "e", but he returns "end", why??

Comment: You want: `listener.substr(9, 1);`

Comment: oh god, thank's ! can you tell difference between substr and substring?

Comment: Or you could use `listener.substring(9, 10);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter to the `substr` function is how many characters to extract (length). The first parameter sets where to start from. You can read more [here in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

So your line of code : `listener.substr( 9, 10 );` basically says "give me 10 characters from the 9th index". However, since there simply isn't 10 characters after the 9th index, the command will return everything that it can which is the rest of the string.

To extract only one character after the 9th index all you'll have to do is use this command:

```
listener.substr( 9, 1 );
```

Alternatively, if you want to **extract a string between two indexes**, you can use the [`substring()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
listener.substring( 9, 10 );
```

Answer (score 5):

The difference between [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is:

```
text.substr(a, b); //a=index to start, b=amount of letters to capture

text.substring(a, b); //a=index to start, b=index to stop
```

So in your case you can use:

```
listener.substr(9, 1);
```

or

```
listener.substring(9, 10);
```